# Kotlin - menuInflater cannot find reference of the xml file

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, optionmenu

I am trying to add create option menu to my activity, however the android-studio sent me this error
`Unresolved reference: chat_app_menu`
Here is my code in Kotlin

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_app_menu)
        return true
    }
```

The line with `menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_app_menu)` show me the error `Unresolved reference: chat_app_menu`
However, I have been create the resource file `chat_app_menu.xml` under `res\menu`\

Here are my import files

```
package com.example.chat_app

import android.R
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
```

My file directory:

[image: My file directory]

What should I do to disable this error to make the app work?

Comment: plz show your import statements. you may be using android.R instead of your app R

Comment: Removed import android.R and import your app R

Comment: @ShaluTD I have added my import files to the question description

Comment: @ShaluTD That works, thanks for your help

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your `com.example.chat_app.R` instead of `android.R`

```
  import com.example.chat_app.R
```